# Turning on/off led with johnny-five and arduino in NW.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arduino, nw.js, johnny-five

I have my board setup with two buttons (with pull-up resistors) and two LEDs. I want each button to turn on corresponding LED and turn the other off.

Code:

```
var five = require('johnny-five');
var board = new five.Board({ port: "COM3" });

board.on("ready", function() {

  // def led
  ledGreen = new five.Pin(13);
  ledYellow = new five.Pin(7);


  buttonRight = new five.Button({
    pin: 2,
    inverted:true
   });

  buttonLeft = new five.Button({
    pin: 3,
    inverted:true
   });

  buttonRight.on("hit", function(value) {
    ledGreen.high();
    ledYellow.low();
    console.log("Button Right - Green ");
  });

  buttonLeft.on("hit", function(value) {
    ledGreen.low();
    ledYellow.high();
    console.log("Button Left - Yellow");
  });

});
```

Console shows correct push states, but sometimes corresponding LED wont turn on, and other one turn off. Its really sporadic. What did I miss? This occurrs only in NW.js evironment, standalone node app runs fine. I have nwjs-j5-fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can try initialize the pins...

```
ledGreen = new five.Pin(13);
ledYellow = new five.Pin(7);

ledGreen.low();
ledYellow.low();
```

this will ensure they are off.

Comment: Did not help. Same unwanted functionality.